# rails page caching, ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, caching

I have an action with pagination, currently I use the below approach to update the content:

```
render :json => { :content => render_to_string( :partial => '..' ), :pagination => render_to_string( :partial => '' ) }, :layout => false
```

So, basically, I'm trying to render only the required parts.

Could you please advice the caching mechanisms I could use in this case? Or is it better(faster) to just use page caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, so just in case someone is looking for something similar, there's an action caching feature, that worked just perfect for me. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Caching/Actions.html

so the only thing I had to do was:

```
caches_action :index, :cache_path => Proc.new { |controller| controller.params }, :if => proc { |controller| controller.request.xhr? }
```

what an amazing piece of software rails is!

Comment: Could this interfere with user sessions? If the cached action is initiated by a 'signed in' user with a session id. Will the session id now be possessed by anyone else who clicks the cached action?